# How to view doctype in generated source code

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I am using an XSL transformation on an xml file to create an xml document.  The problem i am running into is that when i go to view the generated source (the transformed source) i can't see the DOCTYPE attribute of the html so i don't know if its being emitted properly.

Is there any way to view the doctype in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have a weird system, in my case i actually had to just use the doctype as an include file.  I tried the suggestions but for some reason it wasnt rendering the html properly.  Its kind of a weird system they have here at work and im not sure how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it recently but I believe `xsl:output` can be used for this, see [this tutorial](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/index.html) and the options under the various attributes there.

Answer (score 0):

**Read about the `doctype-system` and `doctype-public` attributes of [`<xsl:output>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-output).**

Comment: I found this over and over, but it's not emitting it to the html page and its not making the necessary tweaks to the rendering.  So i really at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens when you serialize the result of the transformation (document tree) yourself. How do you run the transformation and obtain its result?

Answer (score 0):

If you have transitional xhtml, you should include the following `xsl:output` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" 
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" 
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
       <head><title>Test</title></head>
       <body></body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This example produces the following output (with an arbitrary input XML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```